# Letsencrypt: Expiration Dates of Certificate differ

Tags: nginx, debian-jessie, lets-encrypt

I've installed Letsencrypt on my server. The certificates were issued on Feb 22nd, so it's time to renew. The documentation says, `sudo certbot renew` should renew my certificates. But running `sudo cerbot renew` gives this response:

```
The following certs are not due for renewal yet:
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem (skipped)
```

Though, the ssllabs.com SSL report as well as several other SSL test sites say, my certificate would expire on May 23rd. So I checked with other local tools. `ssl-cert-check` states the certificate should be valid until July.

```
> sudo ssl-cert-check -c /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
Host                                            Status       Expires      Days
----------------------------------------------- ------------ ------------ ----
FILE:/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem Valid        Jul 22 2017  66
```

OTOH, `openssl` says, it would expire on May 23rd:

```
echo | openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 -servername example.com 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -dates
notBefore=Feb 22 17:08:00 2017 GMT
notAfter=May 23 17:08:00 2017 GMT
```

So, will my site stop working properly on May 23rd?

*Note: I've replaced the real domain name in all server responses posted here with example.com.*

Answer (score 0):

Oh, that's embarrassing. I've forgot to restart the server after renewing the certificates.

```
> sudo systemctl restart nginx
> echo | openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 -servername example.com 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -dates
notBefore=Apr 23 21:02:00 2017 GMT
notAfter=Jul 22 21:02:00 2017 GMT
```

And the SSL tests now also report the new expiration date in July.